# HSQLDB -Query - insert first record if does not exist

Tags: hsqldb, informix

Note: This question is specifically for HSQLDB and Informix.

I want to insert new entry if not exists in the table and I know we can use exists query to insert based on existing entry.

Eg:

```
INSERT INTO test(column1) 
(SELECT DISTINCT 3 
 FROM test  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test  WHERE column1 =3));
```

Problem is: The EXISTS condition is used in combination with a subquery and is considered to be met, if the subquery returns at least one row. Then only we can use in a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

Comment: Your INSERT looks wrong. Where is the new data that you want to insert when it does not already exist?

Comment: @fredt: In the sample query, the new data is `3`, referenced in the select-list and in the WHERE clause of the EXISTS sub-query.

Comment: I'm not clear what your problem is. Your 'Problem is' paragraph outlines why the INSERT statement does what you say you want done, so I don't understand where there's a hiccup. Is there some other DBMS that handles the issue differently, somehow? If you have proper primary key constraints in place, a simple INSERT will fail to insert if there's already a row in the table with the same key data; all you have to do is decide to ignore the error (you ignore one specific error condition, not all of them). You could use a stored procedure to handle that if you wished. Please clarify you problem.

Comment: My problem very simple. I want to insert one record if it not exists. Criteria - Before first insert there won't be any record in the table.                                               Yes. we can handle these situation in sql using "IF NOT EXISTS".         Query - if not exists(select * from test where column1=1)
insert into test(column1) values(1);

Comment: @fredt - My criteria is table empty. Other than that as usual i'm trying to insert  some data which is not exists. Which means, i'm not aware whether table has empty or has some records that scenario should be handled for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the CREATE table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test(column1 int)
```

This is the INSERT statement for HSQLDB. It uses the SQL Standard syntax and should work with Informix as well:

```
INSERT INTO test(column1) 
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (3)) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test  WHERE column1 =3)
```

This is the SELECT statement to show the rows in the table

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

This is the result of the SELECT

```
 COLUMN1 
 ------- 
 3       

 1 row(s) in 0 ms
```

As Informix does not support the VALUES table constructor, you need to create a separate table with only one row, similar to Oracle's DUAL table. You then use this table inside the SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO test(column1) 
    SELECT 3 FROM single_row_table 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test  WHERE column1 =3)
```

Comment: Its not working. As i described, Initially table is empty and in that case it will return 0 records as inserted and never works.

Comment: The statement inserts one row with `3` when the table is empty.

Comment: Nope. I tried the same with HSQLDB and it's not working.

Comment: I added the CREATE and SELECT statement with the result to the answer.

Comment: Nice! its working for HSQL DB and not working in Informix.